# Repeating a div element after a click

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms, angular-material

What I need is that a button(ADD) when clicked produces a form which consists of a field and a delete button. when you click the button it should erase all form fields and the delete button itself

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" (click)="AddBtn()"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span>Add</button>

<div *ngIf="isformes" >
  
<div>
  <form>
      <table>
          <div>
            
              <tr>
            
                  <td>
                      <mat-form-field ">
                          <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
                          <input matInput placeholder="Name"  autocomplete="off" required>
                      </mat-form-field>
                  </td>
               </tr>
          </div>
       </table>
   </form>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" (click)="DelBtn()"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span>Delete</button>
   </div>
```

Now here in the code at the top we have an add button. And then we have a form with a delete button. What I need is that when I click the add button this form should appear along with the delete button. Then when I click the delete button the form along with delete button should disappear.

Another thing is that if I click the add button for the second time I should get a form along with delete button. For each click this should duplicate.

Comment: you don't need any method only use ngif* directive and in two buttons and first button ngif*="variable" and second button ngif*=!variable" - variable dependt of form is submit or not

Comment: Where is the code for `DelBtn()`?  The HTML is useful, but it's impossible to fix what's broken with the delete button unless we see the JS for the delete button.

Comment: I believe you need to have a look at `*ngFor` directive, You simply loop over an array, delete and add elements, this will automatically reflect in the UI

Comment: @WalterWhite That thing I have already done it but I wanna repeat the forms each time when the button is clicked. I  am stuck in that part

Comment: @HoldOffHunger  I have a very long typescript file and I have only failed tries of the del () and add() function. So pls help

Comment: @OwenKelvin Can you pls provide me an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `*ngFor` you can loop over an array and display contents on the  UI
In the TS file

```typescript
  isformes = true;
  formsArray = [""];
  DelBtn = delIndex => this.formsArray.splice(delIndex, 1);
  AddBtn = () => this.formsArray.push("");
```

HTML FILE

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let i of formsArray; let j = index">
    <div *ngIf="isformes">
      <!-- Other staffs here -->
   </div>
</ng-container>
```

[See Sample Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-itjjaa)

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. It worked. Can you pls explain how the DelBtn () works?

Comment: You pass an index to the function and delete  the item with that index from the array,  Angular will re render the UI when items of the array  change

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest create a new form component which will contain the Input Field and Delete button and then dynamically load that component when user click the Add button.

You need to use componentFactoryResolver which will return you the componentFactory and using that you can create your component dynamically and add that into your UI using ng-template.

```
addForm = () => {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(
      FormComponent
    );
    const component = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);
    component.instance.removeForm.subscribe((x) => {
      this.removeForm();
    });
    this.components.push(component);
  };
```

To Remove your component expose a output param in your formComponent and when user click on that your parent Component it will emit that event and here you can remove that component from UI using below code.

```
 removeForm = () => {
    const component = this.components.find(
      (component) => component.instance instanceof FormComponent
    );
    const componentIndex = this.components.indexOf(component);

    if (componentIndex !== -1) {
      this.container.remove(this.container.indexOf(component));
      this.components.splice(componentIndex, 1);
    }
  };
```

Here is the sample codesandbox:-
https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-butterfly-p8gl9?file=/src/index.html

Comment: Hey this one is a lengthy one. can u give me any short examples

Comment: Its a not a lengthy one, this will satisfy your requirement and also scalability of your application. Do you have a particular limit count how many forms user can add? If not I suggest you to go this way.